# How to provide arguments at startup to application

Tags: c#, command-line, startup

I have been wondering how to provide command line arguments to a application on startup.
I mean what to type in the code, so that a registry entry is created which supplies the command line args:- I have been using the following code, to create a registry entry(so that application launches on startup.

```
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    private void SetStartup()
    {
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
         rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());           

}
```

Can anyone tell me what parameter I should modify in

```
    rk.SetValue()
```

function's arguments to supply command line arguements to my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understund correct you want add command line arguments when your application startup on windows boot?

Then you must do something like that:

```
string cmd = Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + " /arg1 /arg2 /arg3 .....";
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
         rk.SetValue(AppName, cmd);
```

Comment: This works!!! But this opens a blank command prompt window that stays open. On closing the window, the application terminates too. Is there a way to prevent this window from opening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: Project Properties--> Debug-->Command Line Argument, then use these arguments from args in Main(string[] args)

Comment: What i want is how should I modify the parameter in the SetValue() function